# Mystery Book with Golden Fish trapped in Glass

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

There was a series of YA books I read back in the 90's. The general theme was a young boy and his elderly grandfather solving supernatural mysteries in New England.

I can't remember the series name for the life of me. I do remember some surface level details though:

- a mystery involving creepy "apple head" dolls
- the grandfather's love of baseball and listening to it on the radio (NY Yankees?)

  - I think he did this on a porch/cupola/widow's walk outside?
- a mystery involving a slab of glass with golden fish suspended in it

  - I think this object was desired by an order of knights and had something to do with immortality?

Can anyone help me id this series?